# Clear all field inputs in div on hide() jquery: radio button with php function call

Tags: php, jquery, radio-button, show-hide, reset

I'm quite new to jQuery, so I'm having trouble with this.

I have divs that show or hide according to which radio button is selected, but I cannot figure out how to make all of the fields reset if a div is hidden.

The divs have date input fields with php drop down menus that are set to Null or "" in the first option.
There are also some additional radio buttons within the main toggled divs (with more date choices/menus) - So a div within a div with more radio buttons...

Ultimately, I want to clear/reset everything within any hidden divs.

Here is my Jquery (I was getting desperate towards the end and started looking for straight up javascript after a while - don't know what I'm doing there either).

The .desc class is the main radio button choice that shows or hides one of two divs with various other choices.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input[name='date']").change(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $(".desc").hide();
        $("#"+test).show();
        $("input[type='hidden']").remove();
    }); 

    $("input[name='year']").change(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $(".rnge").hide();
        $("#"+test).show();
        $("input[type='hidden']").remove();
    }); 
});
```

Here is the html (sorry for not adding it sooner.

```
<div id="formElementLeft">
    <h4>Date:</h4>
<p>Is this an exact or an approximate date?</p> 
    <p><input type="radio" name="date" value="exact"/>Exact</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="date" value="circa"/>Approximate</p>   
</div>       
    <!--if exact show this-->
<div id="exact" class="desc" style="display:none;">
<p>Enter the exact date: <? echo date_picker(); ?><input type="radio" name="bce_ce"   value="BCE"/>BCE  <input type="radio" name="bce_ce" value="CE"/>CE</p>        
</div>
    <!--if approximate show this-->
<div id="circa" class="desc" style="display:none;">
    <p>Enter a date range.</p>             
    <p>is this a single year or a range of years?
    <p><input type="radio" name="year" value="single"/>Single year</p>
    <p><input type="radio" name="year" value="range"/>Range of years</p>        
    <div id="single" class="rnge" style="display:none;">
    <p><? echo year_picker(); ?></p>
    <p><? echo month_picker(); ?> (optional)</p></div>
    <div id="range" class="rnge" style="display:none;">
    <p>Between <? echo year_picker(); ?><input type="radio" name="bce_ce" value="BCE"/>BCE     <input type="radio" name="bce_ce" value="CE"/>CE;</p> 
    <p>and <? echo year_picker(); ?><input type="radio" name="bce_ce" value="BCE"/>BCE  <input type="radio" name="bce_ce" value="CE"/>CE</p></div>               
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for helping poor, confused me.

Comment: $('#' + test + ' > input').val('');

Comment: This one doesn't seem to do anything. Most of the inputs are originally set to null, so I'm wondering if instead of '' val() should be 0. Sorry if that is a dumb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the tips. It took walking away from it for a day and looking at it with fresh eyes to really understand the syntax. Eventually my tinkering led to this, which actually works(quite proud of myself)!! I nested the .html method in the .hide method so the .html method would be dependent on the .hide method. The trouble with the .each method was that it prevented the divs from showing at all when a radio button was selected.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("input[name='date']").change(function() {
    var test = $(this).val();
    $(".desc").hide(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).html());
        });     
    $("#"+test).show();
}); 

$("input[name='year']").change(function() {
    var test = $(this).val();
    $(".rnge").hide(function(){
        $(this).html($(this).html());
        }); 
    $("#"+test).show();     
});
```

}
});

EDIT:
Discovered a glitch. using the .desc class was not specific enough for one of the divs so it was clearing some things and not allowing one div to open. This is better and does exactly what I want. I had to nest the .html method in the first .show function for this and specify a div id instead of a class to make it work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("input[name='date']").change(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $(".desc").hide();      
        $("#"+test).show(function(){
            $("#exact").html($("#exact").html());
            });
    }); 

    $("input[name='year']").change(function() {
        var test = $(this).val();
        $(".rnge").hide(function(){
            $(this).html($(this).html());
            }); 
        $("#"+test).show();     
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If `.desc` and `.rnge` simply include `input[type='text']` fields, then you could do something like:

```
$(".desc input, .rnge input").val("");
```

Which would reset the text input value to nothing.

However, if you're dealing with radio buttons, you could do:

```
$(".desc input, .rnge input").prop("checked", false);
```

**Finally**: Lets say you had a group of inputs in your list, which might include text inputs, radio buttons, and select lists (but you don't necessarily know what). You could just completely reset the DOM elements altogether by doing something like.

```
$(".desc, .rnge").each(function() {
  $(this).html($(this).html());
}
```

[See an example here](http://jsfiddle.net/cK9kJ/). This just sets the HTML to what it currently is, but in doing so you'll wipe all of your set properties within the `div`. The advantage of doing this, is that your initial values may not have been an empty string. As you said, they could have been some string like "null", and your select lists could have had a default option selected which you'd want to reset.

Comment: The divs won't show using these, but I have been playing around with it. Is this any closer?  `$(".desc").change(function () {
     $(this).is(":hidden"));
     $(this).html($(this).html());`
 });

Comment: I'm still really having trouble with this and I'm not sure if it relates to the php, the jquery or the html. I like the idea of resetting all the DOM elements, by the way.

Comment: If you could be more specific perhaps I could help you? If you think this answer is correct, then it would be helpful if you selected it as such :). Although I see that your answer was edited since which makes the selected answer more relevant, perhaps I'll relook at this when I get time

Answer (score 0):

I have a set of functions that hide any type of field contained within one or more div tags.

**ocultarSeccionesEn** is the main function that performs the hiding and cleaning of all the fields. This function call ocultarDOM function whom just hide/show the div and call **limpiarCamposEnDOM**.
The arguments description:

- **v_aplicar**. Here is the condition that apply the hide/show functionality (hide=true, show=false)
- **a_selector**. This is the find element (".[class name]", "#[Id Name]" or any other type of selector) used to identify the div to hide/show. This argumet has to be an array, if just whant define one div, put inside of array, like: ["#Div-Name"]
- **v_limpiar_campos**. This is just a flag to define if also wants to block the fields when they are hidden

```js
/**
 * Limpia y oculta todos los campos contenidos dentro del selector o selectores definidos el argumento tipo arreglo a_selector
 * @param {bool} v_aplicar  Condición si se va a aplicar la limpieza o no. En caso contrario, si la bandera v_limpiar_y_bloquear es verdadera, se desbloquean los campos únicamente
 * @param {array} a_selector    Arreglo con los textos para identificar la sección o div a limpiar, ejemplo:  con el id (#[nombre]) o la clase (.[nombre])
 * @param {bool} v_limpiar_campos   Bandera que indica si además de limpiar se va a hacer bloqueo de campos. Default es true. 
 */
function ocultarSeccionesEn(v_aplicar, a_selector, v_limpiar_campos = true){
    if(a_selector.length){
        a_selector.forEach(function(v_selector){
            ocultarDOM(v_aplicar, $(v_selector), v_limpiar_campos);
        });
    }
}
```

This is the function called in the main function. In addition to applying hide/show, it calls the function that do the clean fields

```js
/**
 * Limpia y oculta todos los campos contenidos dentro del objeto DOM definido en el argumento o_DOM
 * @param {bool} v_aplicar
 * @param {Object} o_DOM
 * @param {bool} v_limpiar_y_bloquear
 */
function ocultarDOM(v_aplicar, o_DOM, v_limpiar_y_bloquear = true){
    if(o_DOM.length){
        limpiarCamposEnDOM(v_aplicar, o_DOM, v_limpiar_y_bloquear);
        o_DOM.each(function(){
            if(v_aplicar){
                $(this).hide(400);
            }else{
                $(this).show(400);
            }
        });
        
    }
}
```

Here is the function that cleans all types of fields, including those of type *select* with the widget *select2*

```js
/**
 * Limpia todos los campos contenidos dentro del objeto tipo DOM o_DOM
 * @param {bool} v_aplicar  Condición si se va a aplicar la limpieza o no. En caso contrario, si la bandera v_limpiar_y_bloquear es verdadera, se desbloquean los campos únicamente
 * @param {Object} o_DOM    Objeto tipo DOM
 * @param {bool} v_limpiar_y_bloquear   Bandera que indica si además de limpiar se va a hacer bloqueo de campos. Default es true. 
 */
function limpiarCamposEnDOM(v_aplicar, o_DOM, v_limpiar_y_bloquear=true){
    if(o_DOM.length){
        o_DOM.each(function(){
            //var o_input = $(this).find("input");
            var o_input = $(this).find("input");    //Todos los campos input
            var o_select = $(this).find("select");  //Todos los campos select
            var o_textarea = $(this).find("textarea");  //Todos los campos textarea
            //Para campos input
            if(o_input.length){
                o_input.each(function(){
                    if($(this).attr('type') === 'checkbox' || $(this).attr('type') === 'radio'){
                        if(v_aplicar){
                            $(this).prop( "checked", false );
                        }
                    }else{
                        if(v_aplicar){
                            $(this).val("");
                        }
                    }
                });

                //Si además de aplicar limpieza se apliva bloqueo...
                if(v_limpiar_y_bloquear){
                    o_input.attr("disabled", v_aplicar);
                }
            }
            //Para campos textarea
            if(o_textarea.length){
                if(v_aplicar){
                    o_textarea.val("");
                }
                //Si además de aplicar limpieza se apliva bloqueo...
                if(v_limpiar_y_bloquear){
                    o_textarea.attr("disabled", v_aplicar);
                }
            }
            //Para campos select
            if(o_select.length){
                var o_select2 = $(this).find("select[class~='select2']");

                if(o_select2.length){
                    if(v_aplicar){
                        //El widget Select2 no permite limpiar los campos select, debido a eso, primero se debe destruir antes de limpiar el campo
                        o_select2.select2('destroy');
                    }else{
                        //Se vuelve a revertir habilitando de nuevo el widget Select2
                        o_select2.select2();
                    }
                }
                if(v_aplicar){
                    o_select.val("");
                }
                //Si además de aplicar limpieza se apliva bloqueo...
                if(v_limpiar_y_bloquear){
                    o_select.attr("disabled", v_aplicar);
                }else{
                    //Si no se va a bloquear, se vuelve a habilitar el widget Select2
                    if(o_select2.length){
                        o_select2.select2();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```